# Has this list stored the last 3 results?

Tags: python

I have written the code to retrieve the names from a text file and sort them alphabetically. However, how do I not print the duplicate names? For example, the code is

```
 ClassA= open('A.txt','r')
    Classsort= csv.reader(ClassA,delimiter=',')


    if sorting==1:

        name_sort=sorted(Classsort,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        for everyline in name_sort:
            print (everyline)
```

this prints:

```
 [' abba', '1']
 [' bety', '3']
 [' loli', '0']
 [' yano', '4']
 [' yano', '1']
```

but I want it to print

```
[' abba', '1']
[' bety', '3']
[' loli', '0']
[' yano', '4,1']`
```

or print just `[' yano', '4']`,
as I want the highest score for each of the students to be printed

EDIT:
hi the answer worked perfectly thank you. but ihave one last enquiry because if the names and scores have been added to the resuls dict, could i make it so only the users last 3 scores are saved? ie. if yano completed the quiz 2 more times and got 3,7. that only the last 3 results are printed:

```
{' abba': ['1'], ' betyy': ['3'], ' loli': ['0'], ' yano': ['1', '3', '7'], ' gary': ['10'], ' zee': ['4']}
```

Comment: Hint: use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)!

Comment: But whast the point in finding the max if theres only one socre. I first need it to store the resukts of the same name together so it can find a max of them

Comment: @AkshatMahajan aboce

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` and either store the whole list of results for each person or just the max result:

```
>>> results = {}
>>> for student, score in Classsort:
...    results.setdefault(student, []).append(score)
>>> results
{' abba': ['1'], ' bety': ['3'], ' loli': ['0'], ' yano': ['4', '1']}
```

Or just max:

```
>>> results = {}
>>> for student, score in Classsort:
...    results[student] = max(results.get(student, 0), score)
>>> results
{' abba': '1', ' bety': '3', ' loli': '0', ' yano': '4'}
```

Note: Dicts are not ordered, so the fact they printed out in order was coincidence, you need to explicitly iterate through the sorted keys if you want them in order (or look into `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Thanks so much, but what excatly and how do I do sorted keys?

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()